# Disable span tag in PHP for GLPI

Tags: php, html

all.
I am trying to disable no-mandatory fields in GLPI. As the application doesn't offer this option, I am trying to change the source code to do it.

This is the piece of code that is related to the mandatory fields:

```
function getMandatoryMark($field, $force=false) {

  if ($force || $this->isMandatoryField($field)) {
     return "<span class='red'>*</span>";
  }
  return '';
}
```

And this is what I am trying to do:

```
function getMandatoryMark($field, $force=false) {

  if ($force || $this->isMandatoryField($field)) {
     return "<span class='red'>*</span>";
  }
  else{
     return "<span onclick='return false;'>*</span>";
  }
  return '';
}
```

But when I make this change, create tickets page doesn't load. I am not familiar with PHP so I have no idea what is going on...

Comment: `"<span onclick='return false;'>*</span>";` is not a valid php statement. `return "<span onclick='return false;'>*</span>";` would be.

Comment: In general: if you experience any issue when programming php in a web environment you should first of all take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can simply read what the issue is.

Comment: @arkascha this will result in the same problem

Comment: Either you experience another problem afterwards or you are loading the faulty request from cache. Try clearing your browsers cache or make a "deep reload". Apart from that: _did_ you take a look into your http servers error log file as I wrote?

Comment: 2017/04/10 14:00:06 [error] 2993#0: *1 open() "/srv/www/glpi/css/palettes/iland.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.2.2, server: helpdesk.ilandsolucoes.com.br, request: "GET /css/palettes/iland.css HTTP/1.1", host: "helpdesk.ilandsolucoes.com.br", referrer: "http://helpdesk.ilandsolucoes.com.br/front/ticket.form.php"

Comment: What http/php server is that? The file format looks strange...

Comment: It is nginx http server

Comment: That entry in the log file has nothing to do with the issue at hand. There has to be some other issue. No idea what that is, but the statement _with_ return definitely _is_ valid. Maybe you accidentally changed the file permissions whilst editing?

Comment: Yes. It is, I forgot to write it down at first (the problem of not copy and paste). Fixed it in original post. I will keep digging. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to edit the files.

Just create a ticket template, name it (e.g. EasyTicket), and make mandatory, add or hide whatever fields you need. I would suggest using Simplified Interface for end users. Less fuss ;)
[Manage Templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lbLO.png)

Then go to your end users profile (post-only or self-service probably), and choose your Default ticket template (EasyTicket).